# Azure WebJobs in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to create a webjob in python that listens to a queue. I have done the same in c# with the following code,

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("webjobsqueue")] string inputText,
                                        [Blob("containername/blobname")]TextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(inputText);
        }
```

I want the equivalent in python that listens to a queue and trigger the python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *currently* no WebJobs SDK support for python, you can use the [Azure Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) to do so as you don't have to use WebJobs SDK to create a WebJob.